# Is there a way to fold dart enums code blocks in VS Code?

Tags: dart, visual-studio-code

In Dart, an `enum` can occasionally be long:

```dart
enum LoremIpsum {
  dolor,
  sit,
  amet,
  consectetur,
  adipiscing,
  elit,
  sed,
  eiusmod,
  tempor,
  incididunt,
  ut,
  labore,
}
```

In VS Code I am unable to fold these `enum` code blocks (see below) when ever the file is saved as a `.dart` file. Otherwise, in unsaved (like *Untitled-1* with the Dart language mode) documents I am am to fold those `enum` blocks.

```dart
enum LoremIpsum {...
}
```

How can I update the the setting in VS Code to allow code block folding for these `enum` cases?

Comment: I've open an [issue on the official Dart-Code repository](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/issues/3225). As far as I've seen, there isn't really a way to achieve what my question is asking with the current Dart code extension.

Comment: Update on the opened GitHub issue: One of the team members added the [v3.22 milestone](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/milestone/134) to it. Hopefully we'll see this in the v3.22 release of Dart-Code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code folding for `enum` bodies is available in [Dart Code v3.22](https://dartcode.org/releases/v3-22/) and later.